# What is the SQL command to save data in EXCEL sheet?

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

There is a manual option to export the SQl data into CSV but I am looking for SQl command that can save data directly into CSV.

Comment: from where? mysql?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
```

For examlpe:

```
SELECT customer_id, firstname, surname INTO OUTFILE '/exportdata/customers.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM customers;
```

Answer (score 0):

**MYSQL TO CSV COMMAND**

```
SELECT fields
  FROM table
 WHERE conditions
  INTO OUTFILE 'PATH AND FILE' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The CSV file contains lines of rows in the result set. Each line is terminated by a sequence of carriage return and a line feed character specified by the LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' clause. Each line contains values of each column of the row in the result set.

Each value is enclosed by double quotation marks indicated by  FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '”' clause. This prevents the value that may contain a comma (,) will be interpreted as the field separator. When enclosing the values by the double quotation marks, the commas inside the value are not recognized as the field separators

more options (headers, timestamp columns..): 
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/

Another option is the accepted answer to this stackoverflow question: 
stackoverflow.com/questions/3760631/mysql-delimiter-question

**DB2 to CSV**

```
db2 CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD( 'EXPORT TO "C:\UTILS\export.csv" OF DEL MESSAGES ON SERVER SELECT * FROM FASTNET.WLOOKUPTABLEENTRIES' )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is very helpful. I was wandering can we use the same syntax in DBeaver (db2) platform?

Comment: For Db2 11.5 try CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_create_ext_table.html